# Convert sqlite query into NSPredicate for core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I am woking on a core data. I have one query in sqlite. Please help me how to write this for core data so that I can get the equivalent results.

```
SQLite Query: "select * from (select * from WORKDOCUMENT ORDER BY CREATEDDATE ) as WORKDOCUMENT GROUP BY DOCUMENTNAME"
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show details about your model? Thanks. P.S. I removed the downvote since without comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you break out the document name into a separate entity via a to-many relationship:

```
DocumentName:documents <-------->> name:WorkDocument
```

You can now simply fetch the `DocumentName` entity and then sort the result with this sort descriptor (tested):

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"documents.@min.createdDate" ascending:YES]
```